# React-notifications cannot be found

Tags: reactjs, notifications

Currently working on implementing react notifications, but running into an error that says `Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined`, which I believe means that the event being passed into _addNotification is undefined.

```
_handleSuccess: function(data, status, jqXHR) {
    this._addNotification()
    this.setState({
    errors: {},
    loading: false
  });
},
_notificationSystem: null,

_addNotification: function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  this._notificationSystem.addNotification({
    message: 'Notification message',
    level: 'success',
    position: 'bc'
  });
},

_componentDidMount: function() {
    this._notificationSystem = this.refs.notificationSystem;
},

_getNotificationSystemInstance: function() {
    return this
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here it's that you are calling `_addNotification` without any parameter, this function it's expecting an `event` param.

It looks to me that you are loading data from a API service, if that's the case you don't have the `event` object for that case, therefore you either remove `event.preventDefault()` or check if the `event` exist before calling the `preventDefault` function.

```
_addNotification: function(event) {
      event && event.preventDefault(); // <--- Check if event exist!
      this._notificationSystem.addNotification({
        message: 'Notification message',
        level: 'success',
        position: 'bc'
      });
},
```

In the case you are calling `_addNotification` from a button or link, you do need to call `preventDefault`. Therefore, I would recommend adding the check instead of removing it.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! This does solve the issue, however it presents a follow up issue of `Cannot read property 'addNotification' of null` which means that the it will not add a notification to the null _notificationSystem. However, this seems to run contrary to the documentation [here](https://github.com/igorprado/react-notification-system#creating-a-notification). Not sure if this is also a quick fix or deserves a question of its own.